How to annotate mutable structures for mypy
I have this code
def my_foo(x: dict[str, int | float], some_condition: bool) -> None:
    if some_condition:
        x['the_int'] = 1
    else:
        x['the_float'] = 1.0

my_dict = {'some_int': 2}

my_foo(my_dict, True)

mypy (understandably) complains

error: Argument 1 to "my_foo" has incompatible
type "dict[str, int]"; expected "dict[str, int | float]"  [arg-type]
note: "Dict" is invariant -- see
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance
src\type_test.py:23: note: Consider using "Mapping" instead, which is
covariant in the value type

I tried do type-hint using MutableMapping but to no avail:

error: Argument 1 to "my_foo" has incompatible type "dict[str, int]";
expected "MutableMapping[str, int | float]"


This question is very common. The solution is to specify the type explicitly: my_dict: dict[str, int | float] = {'some_int': 2}. There should be a good dupe somewhere.

Slightly besides the point, but I think int | float is equivalent to float (you can pass an int anywhere a float is expected, just not vice versa) so you could simplify the annotation a bit by making it dict[str, float].  You do still need to explicitly annotate my_dict either way.

@Samwise Not quite, since extremely large integers don't have floating-point equivalents.

Try it out: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=a0b763b3fc79a97bde1fb6392ad53e3f

You can try this, create your own dict using TypedDict, you can use dataclass as well.
This code snippet should resolve the issue.
from typing import TypedDict, Union


class MyDict(TypedDict, total=False):
    some_int: int
    the_int: int
    the_float: float


def my_foo(x: MyDict, some_condition: bool) -> None:
    if some_condition:
        x["the_int"] = 1
    else:
        x["the_float"] = 1.0


my_dict: MyDict = {"some_int": 2}

my_foo(my_dict, True)

Tested res
mypy ol.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file


@D.lola's answer is preferable if you have a fixed mapping between what keys are ints and which are float. However, if you don't, you can also just tell mypy that my_dict can contain floats:
my_dict: dict[str, int | float] = {'some_int': 2}

mypy doesn't complain about this code (since it has special casing for literals) and then wont complain for further code.

precisely, this works too, I didn't want to assume; plus x["the_int"] and  x["the_float"] made me infer.
